# Excel - Sum cells down until identifier

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm not too sure if this is possible in an excel formula or if I will need to write VBA to make this happen, but essentially I want the '?' cells to sum all the cells below it until it reaches another Header in Column A. Right now I have the basics of the =IF formula looking like this:

```
=IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1) ISBLANK, null, SUMIF())
```

But I am stuck on the sum portion. Right now the formula is looking 1 cell to the left; seeing if blank, then do nothing or if not blank (header) then it needs to sum all cells below until it reaches another header.

A very weird question but hopefully what i'm asking is making sense. Any thoughts would  be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell `B2`, enter formula :

```
=SUM(B3:B$18)-SUMIF(A3:A$18,"<>",B3:B$18)*2
```

**Edited**

or ,

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B3,,,MATCH(1,FREQUENCY(1,N(A3:A$18<>"")),0)-1))
```

then, copied and pasted to `B6`, `B15`, and `B17`

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution however it only works if all the '?' cells are filled in with this formula. If you paste the formula in B2 only it doesn't work as intended. Anyway around that?

Comment: @cgwoz  try the edited post 2nd formula

Comment: Works like a charm, great solution, thanks.